# Out of stock product need to be least in the product search

Tags: magento-2.1.7

In product search(storefront), the **out of stock products** need to display only after the in-stock products. (But both should need to list). My Magento version is 2.17.

Comment: The search facility is based on relevancy not stock to do this you would need a custom extension or to extend the search functionality.

Comment: i'm new in magento, please give me any reference to extend the search functionality